# Is there some way to avoid using multiple steps to replace ifelse() when it comes to date?

Tags: r, data.table

Since ifelse() strips attributes, I use multiple steps to replace ifelse() when it comes to date.

For example,

```
df <- data.table(a = (1:4),
                 b = as.Date(c("2012-05-05","2014-05-02","2016-01-02","2011-01-02")),
                 c = as.Date(c("2014-02-05","2010-01-02","2015-02-02","2012-03-02")))
year <- 2013
df[, d := as.Date(paste0(format(c, "%Y"), "-", format(b, "%m-%d")))]
df[d <= c, d := as.Dat‌​e(paste0(year, "-", format(b, "%m-%d")))]
```

The example above is quite simple. In real life, I have a more complex situation, which requires making comparison using 3 date columns, totaling 5 different scenarios. Does it mean I need to use 5 steps to complete all the "if else" scenarios? If this is the case, I guess, the advantages of data.table are not best utilized.

Is there some way to avoid using multiple steps?

---

The codes up there is not quite confusion. Sorry for that. The purpose is that,
if the combination of month and day of column b is earlier than that of column c, create a date with the year of 2013, month and day from column b; otherwise, create a date with the year of column c, month and day from column b.

Thanks to  @docendo discimus, I changed the code.

---

One more example

```
year1<-2020
year2<-2025
year3<-2030
df<-data.table(a=(1:4),b=as.Date(c("2012-05-05","2014-01-02","2016-10-02","2011-01-02")),
               c=as.Date(c("2014-09-05","2010-07-02","2015-02-02","2012-03-02"))，
               d=as.Date(c("2008-02-06","2009-08-07","2011-04-04","2010-07-10")))
df[,e:=as.Date(paste0(format(c,"%Y"),"-",format(b,"%m-%d")))];
df[e<=c & e>d,e:=as.Date(paste0(year1,"-",format(b,"%m-%d")))]
df[as.Date(paste0(format(c,"%Y"),"-",format(b,"%m-%d")))<=c & as.Date(paste0(format(d,"%Y"),"-",format(b,"%m-%d")))<=d,e:=as.Date(paste0(year2,"-",format(b,"%m-%d")))]
df[as.Date(paste0(format(c,"%Y"),"-",format(b,"%m-%d")))>c,e:=as.Date(paste0(year3,"-",format(b,"%m-%d")))]
```

The purpose of the above example is make comparison using 3 date columns. When I say compare, I mean use month and day only, regardless year.

```
If b<=c and b>d, change the year to 2020,
if b<=c and b<=d, change the year to 2025,
if b>c, change the year to 2030.
```

I need to use 4 steps to accomplish this. Step 3 and Step 4 becomes ugly since I changed the year of column e in step 2, I cannot use column e to compare with c and d anymore. Is there some way to simplify the above example?

Comment: Can you explain in **words** what your code is doing?

Comment: What the **** are you doing there with `as.Date` and `format`? It makes your example unreadable. Anyway, please provide a representative, minimal reproducible example. For you example here (i.e., a simple `if`/`else` situation), such a two-step approach is exactly what I use.

Comment: `sprintf` would make this a whole lot more readable `as.Date(sprintf('%s-%s-%s', format(c,"%Y"), format(b,"%m"),format(b,"%d")))`

Comment: fyi, you could also rewrite it as `df[,d:=as.Date(paste0(format(c,"%Y"),"-",format(b,"%m-%d")))];df[d<=c,d:=as.Date(paste0(year,"-",format(b,"%m-%d")))]`

Comment: @rawr I see. They should also use the `year`, `month`, `mday` functions for even better readability. The goal seems to be to be to adjust the `b` dates to the same year as `c`?

Comment: @Roland Yes. Adjusting b dates to the same year as c, and then make comparison between b and c.

Comment: Please provide an example that reflects "the real question".

Comment: @Roland I added one more example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `memisc` package provides the `cases` function, which often serves in place of multiple calls to `ifelse`:

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:8)
d$y <- cases(
    d$x == 5 -> "Five",
    d$x < 3  -> "Less than three",
    d$x > 5  -> "More than five",
    rep(TRUE, 8) -> "Otherwise"
)
d
```

Which yields:

```
  x               y
1 1 Less than three
2 2 Less than three
3 3       Otherwise
4 4       Otherwise
5 5            Five
6 6  More than five
7 7  More than five
8 8  More than five
```

This is just a toy example to show off `cases`, but you may find the function useful in your situation. Note that you can replace the conditions `d$x == 5` and the like with any series of logical vectors as long as each is the same length, and `cases` will just catch the first one that evaluates to `TRUE`.

Comment: I recommend benchmarking this solution together with data.table. I assume that performance won't be good.

Comment: @user164385 Thanks for the advice. I will try to combine cases with data.table. Since the performance is quite important. In real example, the data contains millions of rows.

Comment: @user164385 I tried cases function. One problem is that it may have the same problem with ifelse(), striping attributes. The final results are numeric numbers instead of dates. Second thing is that it is slower than multiple steps using data.table.

Comment: @kzhang12 With regard to the stripping attributes on dates, have you tried just running `as.Date(your_numeric_result, origin = "1970-01-01")` to get your date format back?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the attribute stripping or formatting problems you're experiencing? It may be easier to solve that problem than try to come up with a format-preserving workaround that also has high speed.